# Exception with include condition

Tags: php

I want to make an extended Exception for including two php files. If including them fails, 
an Error Message should appear.

I tried the following by now:

```
<?php
    class MeineAusnahme extends Exception {}


    if (isset($_SESSION["login"]) &&
        ($_SESSION["login"] == "true")) {
        @include ("test.php");

        try {
         if(@include("test.php") === FALSE) {

            throw new MeineAusnahme ("<hr />Error Message <hr />" );
         }

 else {
        @include ("test2.php");
        if (@include("test2.php")=== FALSE) {

            throw new MeineAusnahme ("<hr />Error Message.<hr />" );
         }

    } 
        }
              catch(MeineAusnahme $e) {

      die($e);

    }    
    }
```

I am not entirely sure were the mistake is. One guess is, that my if Condition `if(@include("navmitglieder.php") === FALSE)` has the wrong syntax. I am trying it for the first time, so any help is welcome.

Comment: Why not use `file_exists` to test it can be included before calling `include` ?

Comment: What version of PHP are you on?

Comment: I am working with PHP 7. I also read about file_exist, but, if possible I would like to do it with a simple if- condition

Comment: `if( file_exists(...))` IS a "simple if-condition"...